# How to use ng-class binding one more class to one value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I want to bind one more class to a value, like this:

```
ng-class="{first: isTrue, second: isTrue, third: isTrue}"
```

Is `ng-class` Exists any usage can bind them in once, like this? (below code is not working)

```
ng-class="{[first, second, third]: isTrue}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that property name in the single quotes will directly be added to the class when value is true.

```
ng-class="{'first second third': isTrue}"
```

works.

Comment: +2 for don't giving up even after posting question

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know about the `ng-class` directive is that the value you pass in is actually evaluated *roughly* as if it were actually JavaScript. (It actually uses `$scope.$eval`, I believe.) What that means is that you can call a function that is available on the `$scope` to generate your class hash object. I quite like the solution you came up with, taking the classes you need and spacing them out, but what if you had a dynamic list of classes that you wanted to apply to the element? Because the syntax is *roughly* JavaScript, you can't build an object by doing `{list.join(' '): isTrue}` (since that wouldn't be valid in JavaScript). However, what you can do is write a function and add it to the scope which does that:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myList = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

    $scope.allOrNoneClasses = function(list, condition) {
      var o = {};
      if (condition) {
        o[list.join(' ')] = true;
      }
      return o;
    };
    $scope.scopeBasedClasses = function(list) {
      var o = {};
      list.forEach(function(class){
        // this applies a class which matches the scope attribute if
        // the attribute evaluates to a truthy value.
        o[class] = $scope.$eval(class);
      });
      return o;
    };
  });
```

This could then be used in your HTML as follows:

```
<div ng-class="allOrNoneClasses(myList, isTrue)" />
```